# RF24L01 - RF24 Creation Segmentation Fault in Raspberry

Tags: spi, c++, nrf24l01

### What I have

Raspberry Pi 3 B

RF24L01

[RF24 Library TMRh20](https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24)

### How I've Connected It

Based on the [library indications](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/RPi.html):

```
RF24L01 pin | RPi 3B
1 GND       | 9 GND
2 VCC       | 1 (3.3V)
3 CE        | 15 (GPIO22)
4 CSN       | 24 (GPIO8) (CE0)
5 SCK       | 23 (GPIO11) (SPI_CLK)
6 MOSI      | 19 (GPIO10) (SPI_MOSI)
7 MISO      | 21 (GPIO9) (SPI_MISO)
```

[image: Pic of Pins]

### The Code (Executable, built using TMRh20 library)

```
#include <RF24/RF24.h>

using namespace std;

// Pin 22 used for CE, as said before in pin connections
RF24 radio(22,0);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  printf("Starting...\n");

  radio.begin();

  printf("Done\n");

  return 0;

}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

### Problem / Question

As you can see, a `segmentation fault` error (in Spanish) happened. I've also activated the SPI interface using:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

So, ***why do I get this execution error?***

**Isn't the initialization valid?**

### Update

I've also tried moving ping CE from RF24, that was connected to GPIO22 (pin 15) to pin 26 (CE1), because I [saw this](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/) in the dependence BCM2835.

Then, I enabled SPI again, built and execute again, getting the same result.

Comment: You might as well start learning to use a debugger.  Run `gdb ./test` (if gdb is not installed, `sudo apt install gdb`).  When you get to a prompt, type `run`.  The seg fault will be caught, and you will get another prompt.  Enter `bt` (backtrace).  If the output is not too long, cut and paste it here.  Please don't use screenshots for text.

Comment: Already tried gdb @goldilocks, but it gives me "illegal instruction" after `gdb ./test`

Comment: "Illegal instruction" implies code that was compiled for the wrong architecture, although in that case it probably wouldn't link.  If you compiled it on the pi, you may be out of luck at this point.

Comment: As you are compiling on the Pi I would replace the `arm-linux- ... -abi=hard` with the letters `gcc`

Comment: ++ for the very well formatted question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I noticed that building the library as told on the documentation with:

```
sudo make install -B
```

Run inside another `configure`, which deletes yours. That said, what I did was, from my $~ directory:

```
cd ./RF24/
sudo ./configure --driver=SPIDEV
```

Went to the file `Makefile.inc` and replace (as told by Joan in a comment):

```
CC=...-gcc --> CC=gcc
CXX=...-g++ --> CXX=g++
```

Then, install the library (notice no `-B` option, so my `Makefile.inc` file is not replaced by the new created by a new run of configure):

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Finally, go to the examples folder (where my program is) and compile it. Modifying first my makefile of course:

```
cd ./examples_linux/
```

Edit Makefile

```
PROGRAMS = receiver
```

Compile and run:

```
sudo make
./receiver
```

My program now executes fine without any error and without needing sudoers.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue, and discovered that it will segfault if you do not run the program as root (sudo). It would be great if it could be more helpful, but alas. Try putting `sudo` in front of the `./test`

Determined the problem by finding this comment in the source code:

> If the library runs with any other effective UID (ie not root), then
>     bcm2835_init() will attempt to open /dev/gpiomem, and, if
>     successful, will only permit GPIO operations. In particular,
>     bcm2835_spi_begin() and bcm2835_i2c_begin() will return false and all
>     other non-gpio operations may fail silently or crash.

Source: https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/95ef8bdadf9068796444151c162749eb5bad4c26/utility/RPi/bcm2835.h#L63-L67

Comment: You leave me totally stunned. I found yesterday a solution, based on some differences on compilation and installation. Will post on another answer.

Comment: @BtcSources Cool, I'm interested in seeing what it was. If my solution is also valid I'd appreciate accepting as answer ;-) I'm also considering contributing a PR to throw instead of segfaulting to help people that don't have time to dig through the source code and run gdb on it like I did.

Comment: Done Paul =) I'll upvote yours as it's a valid answer, but will mark as accepted answer mine, since these were the steps that worked for me to solve it. Thanks!