# Is there any RF24 (non +) library working (tested) with Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, nrf24l01

### What I've seen

I've been several days looking and trying to build a little program for **RPi3**, which aims to use RF24 through **SPI**.

After research, I've found the following libraries, tried to use them all, and no one worked fine, I've always obtained an error. I've even opened a post here looking for a solution for one of them, but nobody appears to know how to do it, nor I've been able to solve it myself.

- [TMRh20](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/index.html) ([post trying to make it work, made](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80326/rf24l01-rf24-creation-segmentation-fault-in-raspberry[1]) in C++) (this one also has a python wrapper, I've installed it, currently trying to create a little program to try if it works)
- [pynrf24](https://github.com/jpbarraca/pynrf24) (python port) (obtained an error saying channel must be an `int`, in a GPIO library, used by this library, can't debug it all)
- [nRF24](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24) (TMRh20 fork if I'm not mistaken, bit more updated) (got an error on execution time)

Notice, that I've been trying at least one day per library solving problems, like dependencies, spidev names inside the code that doesn't match with the RPi names, etc.

This one I've not tried yet:

- [ChienDesEnfers/RF24](https://github.com/ChienDesEnfers/RF24) (another TMRh20 fork, this one has far more changes)

### My questions

All of this libraries have been used or developed for RPi 1, 1B, 2, etc. But no one seems to have been tested or be prepared to be used with RPi3.

Aside from the **pins change**, which anyone can perform by just looking to the RPi3 GPIO name,

1. should there be any other kind of thing to change to make this libraries work?
2. **Do you know any of these libraries (or another one I've not listed here) to work with RPi3?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some code for my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library.

I posted the code as an [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/77353/13650) to a similar question.

It was tested between a PiB and Pi3B.

It requires the pigpio library and the pigpio daemon to be running.  Both are installed in recent Raspbian images.

Comment: Thanks @joan, I'll give it a try and tell you what happens, or verify and upvote the answer =)

Comment: It works! I still have to tweak it to match my arduino tx setup, but it actually works (compile and exec without errors) =) Thanks again

Comment: There is nothing special about the implementation, all I did was read the datasheet! You should be able to port it to a language of your choice.